# Using PolarAxes but without the circle?

Tags: plotting

I would want to know a way to get rid of the circle when using `PolarAxis`.

Is there such a thing as *Polaraxestyle*?

Comment: As stated in the documentation for [`PolarAxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarAxes.html): "PolarAxes->False draws no axes."

Answer (score 6):

If you search

```
FullForm[PolarPlot[Sin[3 t], {t,0,Pi}, PolarAxes->Automatic]]
```

for the word Circle you will find a single instance in that.

If you study the structure around that carefully and then evaluate

```
PolarPlot[Sin[3 t], {t,0,Pi}, PolarAxes->Automatic]/.List[Circle[__]]->Sequence[]
```

then you get your plot, but without the circle.

Be really careful using this, particularly if your plot includes any other circles.

Comment: yes thank you !

Comment: One can also use `DeleteCases[]`: `DeleteCases[PolarPlot[Sin[3 t], {t, 0, Pi}, PolarAxes -> Automatic], Circle[__], ∞]`